# Passing an Array into a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a web service to populate a selection list and I now need to do the same for a number of selection lists ideally using the same method to try and limit the amount of code. Here's the method I use to make my web service call:

```
function GetColourReferences(self) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/GetColourReferences',
        success: function (data) {
            self.colourReferences(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried something similar to the following but I can't get it to work - is it even possible?

```
function GetReferences(self, list, refUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: refUrl,
        success: function (data) {
            list(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's how I'd call it (I'm using Knockout):

```
GetReferences(self, self.colourReferences, '/GetColourReferences');
```

Thanks for looking :)

Comment: On a general note. You never (never, *never*, **NEVER**) use synchronous Ajax calls. Forget that they exist.

Comment: Yes, DO NOT USE SYNCHRONOUS AJAX CALLS they will really mess you up this is almost 100% guaranteed. Either nest everything in callbacks manually, and/or use caolan's async library to manage the callbacks: https://github.com/caolan/async.

Comment: To pass an array into a function, simply do this: myfunction(myarray). But in your case why don't you just have an array of selection lists, then loop through that array, and call whatever function you want for each of the selections? You can use caolan's async library to ensure that this is done asynchronously AND in sequence (i.e. waiting for async to finish before doing next one) by using async.forEachSeries and/or async.waterfall.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comments - the reason I'm using async calls is because my form uses a lot of validation, showing and hiding panels, etc. The problem I have is that my web services take time to return the data for the select lists and by the time they return, it's too late to select entries in the list. The library sounds interesting though so I'll look into that - thanks :)

Comment: With regards to passing the arrays as parameters, I though I should be able to do it. I'll have to revisit my code and see what's going on.

Comment: You don't need another library to manage async calls. jQuery has that built in (via `.when()` and `.then()`). Also you are doing *synchronous* calls, as per your code samples, and you should not do that. Can you explain when the values should be loaded? Only once? Regularly? Will they reload when something changes or will they stay the same after the initial load?

Comment: I'm using Knockout and very little jQuery. In a nutshell, my model declares and initialises all of its data and observables, loading in select list data from web services. It can then process a query string parameter which updates the KO model. Unfortunately, I have a number of divs which are hidden and only appear on selection of a given selection list; and updating the model doesn't work properly with async web services as the binding to show a given div tends to occur before the selected entry can be bound to the selection list; means the div remains hidden and the list is unselected.

Comment: This sounds like you should fix the timing issues in your web app first. If you set up a basic [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows your problem I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Dude whatever your excuse listen to the tips from the others NEVER NEVER use Sync call especially if your backend is slow to process or if you have some messy ui requirement.

2) sort out your closure and learn how to scope method of an object and you will fix your problem but I'm going to be nice and point you in the right direction.

3) This don't work simply because you pass a reference to the function and not a reference to the method of the object so cleverly called self (WTF have you heard of semantic) That aside list is function that has lost the object scope and this is where the problem is!

```
function GetReferences(self, list, refUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: refUrl,
        success: function (data) {
            list.call(self, data);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that help.